# How to use SMOTE on structure list data while preserving structure

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

My unbalanced training data is in the following structure:

```
[
[
[2.2079929344226097e-05,
  7.354293068578783e-06,
  1.713310445263026e-05],
 [2.2079929344226097e-05,
  7.354293068578783e-06,
  1.713310445263026e-05]
],
[
[3.2079929344226097e-05,
  1.354293068578783e-06,
  2.713310445263026e-05],
 [2.2079929344226097e-05,
  2.354293068578783e-06,
  3.713310445263026e-05]
],
[
[4.2079929344226097e-05,
  4.354293068578783e-06,
  4.713310445263026e-05],
 [4.2079929344226097e-05,
  4.354293068578783e-06,
  3.713310445263026e-05]
]
]
```

and my labels look like this:

```
[
[1, 1],
[1, 0],
[1, 1]
]
```

If I flatten the data, I can run SMOTE via sklearn successfully with this code:

```
X = data
y = labels

sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
X, y = sm.fit_resample(X, y)
# keras function to convert multiclass to float vector
y = to_categorical(y, dtype='float32')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)
```

However, I get this error trying to run the code on the structured data/labels:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-60c6ccd3d7d6> in <module>()
      3 
      4 sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
----> 5 X, y = sm.fit_resample(X, y)
      6 y = to_categorical(y, dtype='float32')
      7 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    554                     "Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if "
    555                     "your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) "
--> 556                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))
    557 
    558         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like object dtypes

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: have you tried passing to SMOTE np.argmax(y, axis=1).reshape(-1,1) ?

Comment: Yes, I get this error:    AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Comment: so y is 1-dimensional... have you tried simply this y.reshape(-1,1) ?

Comment: Yes, same error.

Comment: what's the shape of X ?

Comment: When I run np.array(X).shape, I get (111,), which is how many documents there are in this corpus. Each document has 2 sequences and each sequence has 3 floats.

Comment: X must be 2-dimensional: (n_sample, n_col)